# What is the Difference between of something and of the something?

Tags: definite-article, sentence-structure

I have doubt what to use for making correct sentence like something bellow:

1. Name of school is xyz
2. Name of the school is xyz

Which one/both is correct ?

**OR**

do they have any difference in its usage ?

Comment: Your title does not match what you are asking in your question. "something" could be anything...

Comment: @user3169 please feel free to edit the title if some mistakes are there, as I am not an English origin person :)

Comment: Generally, you won't find *'a name'* unless you are talking about more than one name. For instance, *Neelkanth is a name of Shiv'*. Rest in almost all cases, you'll find *the name*.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are talking about a specific school (xyz) you need to use *the* for the definite nouns *name* and *school*:

> **The** name of **the** school is xyz